Change spaces between integrals in esint
I would like to change the spaces between integral signs in esint package. I found the following in their documentation:

You can customize the space between integral sign in multiple integrals. You have to modify lines 12 and 13 of the esint10.mf file: tdec# and ddec# are spaces
between signs. If you modify esint10.mf, delete esint10.tfm, the generated
*.pk files, and run METAFONT on esint10.mf. Of course, you have to remove
pub files: the type 1 version will not be modified!

Unfortunately I don't know anything about metafonts and I don't know exactly how to do it. I am using texlive on windows. Can you please explain me how to do this step by step.
Thank you very much

You need to 1. make a duplicate of all Metafont sources under a different name. 2. Make the fonts. 3. Digitize them to get PostScript versions. 4. Write a new package. 5. Write the mapping files. 6. Deploy everything in the local TeX tree. You see that's no beginner's endeavor.

Especially as you would need to generate type1 scalable fonts from the metafont source for modern use, generating a new font is not really a simple "step by step" process.
For multiple integrals it is usually much simpler to adjust the spacing between single integrals via TeX rather than making a new font.

\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\iiint{\int\mkern-8mu\!\int\!\mkern-8mu\int\nolimits}
\newcommand\iiintb{\int\mkern-10mu\!\int\!\mkern-10mu\int\nolimits}
\newcommand\iiintc{\int\mkern-6mu\!\int\!\mkern-6mu\int\nolimits}

\begin{document}


\[A+\iiint_0^n\]
\[A+\iiintb_0^n\]
\[A+\iiintc_0^n\]


\end{document}

Here the outer \int ensure the construct has \mathop spacing, the two \! remove the \thinmuskip that is placed automatically between adjacent \mathop symbols and then the negative \mkern can be adjusted to whatever spacing you need, as shown.
